# Updating AWS Elastic Bean has encountered a . How to resolve this?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

While doing incremental publish to an elastic beanstalk instance through eclipse, it fails multiple times suggesting to turn of incremental deployment. I found multiple soutions saying turn off incremental deployment. I don't see option to turn off this feature.
How to do that? Also is there any other way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

in Eclipse, double-click on your Elastic Beanstalk Environment from the AWS Explorer view.  That will bring up a custom editor for the environment's properties, configuration, event log, etc.  On the first tab in the editor, you should see a section titled "AWS Elastic Beanstalk Deployment".  In this section there is a checkbox you can uncheck to disable incremental deployment.

This page in the Elastic Beanstalk Developer Guide has a screenshot and a little more info:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.managingappenv.html